# After converting text to link, cursor up/down does not respond

Tags: bug, status-declined, firefox

When editing text and some text is converted to a link using either the [image: link] button or <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>, the cursor up/down does not respond anymore.

This happens in Firefox (v39 and v40) but does not seem to affect editing in Chrome nor IE.

Comment: Perfect work with the link image you posted :)

Comment: I have no idea if you meant that sarcastically...

Comment: Not at all.. I really mean it.

Comment: lol.. thanks :) snag-it + imgur plugin is your friend

Comment: on v40 on a mac I only have problems with the down arrow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current Firefox version is 38. We don't support pre-release browser versions, because almost always issues like this are inevitable browser beta bugs.

Comment: v38 won't install for me (it sees v39 as newer), but I assume you try to say it works in v38 (?). If so, ok, lets hope Mozilla stop changing things that works :)

Comment: Yeah, I could not reproduce what you're describing in current stable Firefox, and the behavior you're seeing sounds very typical of a browser pre-release issue.